# PHP Localization Mechanism

Tags: java, php, localization

What's the best way to localize a PHP page? We have several PHP pages that need to be deployed to other countries. They are hard-coded in English now. I am looking for a mechanism to externalize the text and localize it.

Something like ResourceBundle in Java would be great. We don't use any frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) support in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), I think it would be best to use that.